# Unexpected Type Mismatch Error when Checking If Array Element Equals Space

Tags: excel, vba

For clarity, I've posted my entire code below and all the functions it uses. The goal of this macro is to read data that looks like this: XY05-09 XY37-49 and generate labels based on the range in the cell. In this case it would make XY05, XY06, XY07 etc. My problem is with the line

```
If ArrOfChar(element) = " " Then
```

Which returns a type mismatch. I've used MSgBox to output each element as they are being created and it looks to store the space as an element but for some reason I can't compare the element's value to " ". I've dug around for awhile but had no luck fining an explanantion as to why this is. Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Label_Generator_Button1_Click()
Dim InitialString As String
Dim Prefix As String
Dim FirstNum As Integer
Dim LastNum As Integer
Dim IsLastNum As Boolean
Dim InsertZero As Boolean

Dim ArrOfChar() As String

Prefix = ""
FirstNum = 0
LastNum = 0
IsLastNum = False
InsertZero = False
InitialString = Range("A1")


ReDim ArrOfChar(Len(InitialString) - 1)
For i = 1 To Len(InitialString)
    ArrOfChar(i - 1) = Mid$(InitialString, i, 1)
    'MsgBox ArrOfChar(i - 1)
Next



For Each element In ArrOfChar
    
    If ArrOfChar(element) = " " Then 'If space, reset all to zero, new number WHY IS THIS TYPE MISMATCH
        For i = FirstNum To LastNum
            Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value & Prefix
            If InsertZero = True And i < 10 Then
                Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value & "0"
            End If
            Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value & i & " "
        Next i
        Prefix = ""
        FirstNum = 0
        LastNum = 0
        InsertZeroFirst = False
        InsertZeroLast = False
        IsLastNum = False
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If
    
    If ArrOfChar(element) = "-" Then 'If a dash is used, flag the system to switch to last number and make insert zero false
        IsLastNum = True
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If
    
    If IsLetters(ArrOfChar(element)) = True Then 'If is a letter add to prefix
        Prefix = Prefix & ArrOfChar(element)
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If
    
    If ArrOfChar(element) = "0" And FirstNum = 0 Then ' If is 0 and the first number, set flag to insert leading 0
        InsertZero = True
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If
    
    If IsNumbers(ArrOfChar(element)) = True Then
            If IsLastNum = False Then
                FirstNum = CInt(ArrOfChar(element))
                GoTo NextIteration
            End If
            If IsLastNum = True Then
                LastNum = CInt(ArrOfChar(element))
                GoTo NextIteration
            End If
    End If
    If ArrOfChar(element) = "0" And FirstNum > 0 Then 'If is 0 and not the first number, multiply first number by 10. If we are given a 5 then the next is zero, multuplying by 10 gives us our aditional place
        FirstNum = FirstNum * 10
        GoTo NextIteration
    End If
NextIteration:
Next element
End Sub



Function IsLetters(Str As String) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(Str, i, 1))
        Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            IsLetters = True
        Case Else
            IsLetters = False
            Exit For
    End Select
Next i

End Function


Function IsNumbers(Str As String) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(Str, i, 1))
        Case 49 To 57
            IsNumbers = True
        Case Else
            IsNumbers = False
            Exit For
    End Select
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `For Each element In ArrOfChar` your `element` **IS** an element itself of the array and not the **index** of an element.

Therefore `ArrOfChar(element - 1)` fails because `element` is not a number!

Either use `element = " "` to access the element or change your loop to a indexed loop like:

```
Dim idx As Long
For idx = LBound(ArrOfChar) To UBound(ArrOfChar)
    Debug.Print idx, ArrOfChar(idx)  ' print idx and value of the element
Next idx
```

This will loop from the first element to the last element and the `idx` is the index of the element.

Make sure you use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly. I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I don’t usually use the For Each statements to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because `element` is a character, not an integer. VBA is not able to evaluate `element - 1`

To loop through, you will need to change element to something like this.
`For element = 1 To Len(InitialString)`